# How can I setup up an a pre-populated pdf based on what was entered?

Tags: customization

So to give you more info on what I need, I have application form that gathers a lot of information from the clients but I need to create a PDF form that they can print out and sign that contains specific data from the application but also has other information on like my letterhead and some info regarding the application.

So I basically want to pre-populate an exiting PDF form with selective information from the application like name surname and ID for the different clients. SO if I have 5 clients info on 1 application it should pull through all 5 applicants details to one form and so on.

I'm currently using contact form 7 to gather the information I need and manually creating the forms to sign.

I have looked into the add on - dynamic text extension but i can't seem to configure it to do what I need

Hope you can help.

Comment: There's a script called FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) that can generate pdfs on the fly. It can include your letterhead by default, then you can dynamically add data from the application. Pretty code-intensive but works reliably.

Comment: This is either a generic PHP library question about filling in forms in PDF files via PHP, or a contact form 7 3rd party plugin question. The first would be better on stackoverflow, though recommending a library to do it is out of scope, and the latter would be better in contact form 7's support forum.